# Using the react-virtuoso TableVirtuoso component how do I print the entire table?

Tags: react-virtuoso

When I print a page containing a TableVirtuoso component, I only get the portion of the table that is visible.  How do I instruct TableVirtuoso to render the entire table in prep for printing?

Comment: hi glenn, could you share the code you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

Virtualization here is used mainly for rendering a subset of data, for sake of speed and browser memory. I think it's not a good practice to use the same component for printing.

However, you can disable the virtualization by rendering the whole table on `beforeprint` event, user will wait for the DOM to be built, and then he can print the data. Virtualization can be then enabled (with tableVirtuoso) on `afterprint` event.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeprint', () => {
    // Code to render the entire table
});
window.addEventListener('afterprint', () => {
    // Code to revert back to virtualized table
});
```

However, I guess you use TableVirtuoso for the purpose it should be used for -- visualizing large amount of data. Keep in mind the users can be pretty much blocked if you allow them to load all data at once into the DOM. Even the browser may crash and they won't print anything.